# Image texture material causing transparency

Tags: rendering, mesh, texturing, materials, uv

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLe5j.png]So when I apply an image texture material to my mesh for some reason in rendered mode the mesh becomes transparent I can see through it.. I don't know what when wrong but I'd appreciate some help... Image below of the sign post that's transparent.. 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLe5j.png]

Comment: Please post Material Node setup screen shot

Comment: I've done so thank you

Comment: Interesting. Feel free to send your file for a deeper analisys: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2

Comment: Very well theni will do so I'm assuming it has something to do with the layers but I can't figure it out